# CSS behaving differently in IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm trying to create a small navigation menu, however IE seems to render it differently, completely messing it up.

Here's what html/css I'm using (jsfiddle renders it correctly, as does `chrome`):

http://jsfiddle.net/Seytonic/gmp975sm

However IE renders it like this (I omitted the bootstrap in the jsfiddle):

[image]

EDIT: I'm using IE 11

Comment: Just FYI, you are missing a `</div>` before `</body>` in your fiddle.

Comment: Ah thanks, must have missed it when copying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one reason why it's important to declare a width on floated elements. If you don't, the box size may render differently across browsers.

Try adding `width: 330px` to the `#navigation` container.

[**Revised Demo 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/gmp975sm/1/)

The 330px is just for example. You can use relative units, like percentages or ems, as well.

Again, to avoid unpredictable browser behavior, also specify a width for the two floated child elements:

```
#navbar li { width: 49.5%; }
```

Then adjust the spacing between the boxes on the top row:

```
#projects { margin-left: .5%; }
#about { margin-right: .5%; }
```

Lastly, `width` by default only includes the [*content box*](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp). Make it also account for *padding* and *border* with [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/):

```
html {  box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit;}
```

[**Revised Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/gmp975sm/3/)

Comment: If I do that the bottom email container is not flush on the left hand side with the box above, the difference may not show up much on jsfiddle, but trying it in chrome and IE it's quite noticeable.

Comment: I tested on Chrome, FF and IE11. Everything lined up. If you specify a width for the container (`#navigation`), the floated elements inside will respect the boundary. Without an explicit width, the browsers may handle the sizing differently (as you have seen).

Comment: In chrome I get this: http://prntscr.com/9iknxa scaled a bit more I get this: http://prntscr.com/9iko3u

Comment: Actually, it must be something to do with bootstrap, if I remove the bootstrap references it is much more aligned, however, there is still a small gap http://prntscr.com/9ikozt

Comment: What browser have you seen different sizes when floated? That should never happen! And the behavior is defined in the spec.

Comment: @Rob, none of the floats had defined widths in the original code. The sizing of a floated child element was way off in IE11.